# apache spark: spark history server: Not showing sql tab and also the execution details

Tags: apache-spark

I am runing spark history server. I am not able to see sql tab and also other execution information.

amy spark-default.conf

```
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir file:///home/simha/app/spark_events
spark.history.fs.logDirectory file:///home/simha/app/spark_events
```

[image]